# Comparison of db strategies for polymorphic many to many: RDB vs. NoSQL

Tags: postgresql, inheritance, sqlalchemy, nosql, many-to-many

I'm choosing a database approach, and still at the stage where the decision is at a very highly level; I'm trying as hard as possible to fit my problem into Postgres, for its enormous maturity and feature set, but I'm not at all familiar with this level of SQL complexity, and wonder if the core relationship I have in mind might just be better expressed in a different model. (I've only found other answers that ask about this within a given framework.)

The driving issue (within a larger setup) is the ability to associate Features (ex. large, weight, type, but a VARYING set of these), that have been assigned by a specific Classifier (model), with Things. These don't just show that a Thing IS 'large,' but that it was ASSESSED for 'largeness,' by a particular Classifier. And most difficult within a RDBMS, the VALUE of 'large' might be binary, while 'weight' is an integer, 'type' is a category, etc. In other words,

```
 Thing1 --> large=true   (says model 1)
        |-> weight=3     (says model 2)
        |-> type='great' (says model 3)

 Thing2 --> large=false (says model 1)
        (not assessed for 'weight')
        |-> type='lousy' (says model 4)
```

In a nutshell, storing (thing, feature, value, classifier) tuples, where Things and Features are many to many, and values will be of different types, for different features.

**Approach 1: Relational**

There is a table of Things. There is also a PARENT class Features, which (or maybe its children?) has a many-to-many relationship with Things. Each particular feature, Large, Weight, Type, is a CHILD class of 'Feature', and each of the Child >-< Things junction table also holds the (consistently typed) values of the Things, for that particular feature. In other words,

```
ThingTypeValues
-------------------
thing.id | type.id | 'great'
thing.id | type.id | 'lousy'
...

ThingLargeValues
---------------------
thing.id | large.id | true
thing.id | large.id | false
...
```

This allows me to get all 'thing.features,' because they share Feature as a parent, and still query the full (mixed-type) description of the Thing, while having consistent types within tables; it also allows me to (better) avoid the problem of accidentally having a 'great' and a 'grreat' and a 'Great,' by making each Feature-child be its own table (instead of just a string, within an object, or an ever-being-updated ENUM), where I can easily check to see what existing options there are for labels, by treating each Feature as a well-respected, separate-identity, thing.

As a last point, if there were only one Classifier (thing APPLYING Features) then there could be a single table, with every column being a Feature, and every cell having a Value, or NULL, to indicate that it wasn't assessed for that Feature -- but because there will actually be a very large number of Models, each giving their opinion, this sounds like a pretty ugly strategy, for each one to have their own enormous, mostly empty, and always growing (as we add more Features), table.

HOWEVER, using SQLAlchemy for example (I'm by far most familiar with python), I now have to use `association_object`s and `AbstractConcreteBase`s and it all looks quite nasty, to my untrained eye.

** Approach 2: NoSQL**

Suddenly mixed type, which appears to be the biggest problem, is no longer a problem! I can have a set of features, and each with a type, and a value, and associate them each with an answer. If I want to be careful with not fat-fingering my categories, I can have a function that validates them, or a process that checks against existing Features before adding a new one. These sound more error-prone, certainly, but I'm asking this because I don't know how to evaluate the tradeoff, how to approach the best solution in EITHER framework, or if something entirely different is a much better idea anyway.

Opinions, suggestions, technologies, philosophies, and donations, all welcome.

Comment: Multiple columns (one for each value type) and a CHECK constraint to ensure that exactly one is non-NULL might be an option. A `jsonb` column (together with a CHECK to ensure that it has the expected structure) might be an option.

Comment: @muistooshort Apologies I want to make sure I understand -- This is a table where each row is associated with a single Thing, and represents a SINGLE Feature, so each Thing may have multiple rows, and each row also has a Classifier.id with it? So one simple table for all Features and Values, in exchange for accepting the overhead of the one-hot encoding? That does sound MUCH simpler to store. Would it get really ugly to query, when I had to always pick out the non-NULL cell? (Or is that what jsonb's for?)  And does the inherited strategy sound flawed, if I have the wherewithal to implement it?

Comment: Your main problem seems to be that you need to store values with various types in the same place, right? So you have whatever IDs you need for your FKs and then an `int` column, `text` column, ... to cover the values. Yes, looking up values could be unpleasant. A single `jsonb` column should make that cleaner; you could have all the goodness of a proper RDBMS (referential integrity, joins, ...) and heterogenous storage via JSON at the same time.